# How to scroll through DataGrid columns without having items?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

i have a question with the WPF DataGrid, when the items is not empty , HorizontalScrollBar is normal. but if items is empty , there's no  HorizontalScrollBar even if the columnsheader need to be scrolled to to see. how can i see the HorizontalScrollBar?
i have found a post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/64b18ca9-f9f5-4748-86a8-c5b40815fd9b. but not fix my problem.
thanks a lot.

Comment: I see what you mean.  If CanUserAddRows=false the horz scrollbar is disabled.

Comment: yes,because the columnheader is not in the scrollviewer's scrollcontent

Comment: You fins an answer is here at the below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466878/6856623

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue and our solution was to keep a single empty row in the grid if there is no rows anymore. This keept horizontal scrollbar active.

Comment: no other solutions? i have found a solution in listview,but not work in datagrid.