# horizontal scrollbar not showing on datagrid when data is empty and headers do not fit on screen

Tags: c#, xaml

I have tried the following :

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: can i assume you mean `DataGridView`? In which case, you don't need any scrollviewer as it will automatically add scroll bars as needed

Comment: @Takarii i think @Ankita means the `DataGrid` and it is true that the grid does not show scrollbars when there is no content but the header are not fitting into the grid. Additional to your comment i also don't know why there is a ScrollViewer..

Comment: A fast "workaround" for this is setting the `IsReadOnly` property to `False` because then you always have a empty row for editing in your `DataGrid`

Comment: @Jens is there no way to get the scroll bars to view the headers without data in the grid?

Comment: In that case, you need to show us more of your code

Answer (score 0):

There must be a possibility to do it, because [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.com/) has done it!

---

Lets assume that you have e.g. this class:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public int LongPropertyNameA;
    public int LongPropertyNameB;
    public int LongPropertyNameC;
    public int LongPropertyNameD;
    public int LongPropertyNameE;
    public int LongPropertyNameF;
}
```

---

The normal approach looks like this: 
[image: Data Grid] 
The Headers are hidden.
The XAML Code looks e.g. like this:

```
<busGeneratorMvvm:CustomDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourData}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

---

When you use the WPT Toolkit DataGrid Library (called Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.dll) the grid looks like this with the scrollbars you want:
[image] 
The XAML Code looks e.g. like this:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourData}" >
```

where `xcdg` is the namespace defined in the Window tag with this XAML Code:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        ...
    >
```

---

**Conclusion:** 
If you want it very easy download the Xceed WPF Toolkit and use the `DataGridControl`.

- Download the .dll from the website (search the internet for the free version)
- Add the .dll to the references of your project
- Use and enjoy the `DataGridControl`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

the below solution will work. since listbox width is set to datagrid width scroll bar will be visble.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox Width="{Binding ElementName=myGrid,Path=ActualWidth}"></ListBox>
                <DataGrid Name="myGrid"></DataGrid>
            </Grid>

        </ScrollViewer>
```